# what's the name of powerset and then sum within every susbet.?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Given a finite set of vectors $V = \{ v_1, \cdots, v_i, \cdots, v_n\}, v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can define a mapping of sum $S: V \to \mathbb{R}^n := \sum_{v_i\in V}v_i$. where $S(\emptyset) = \vec{0}$

There is also a powerset operation of $P(V)$. which give the set of all possible subset of $V$.

Then what is the name of this set $\{ S(U) | U \in P(V) \}$ ?

Comment: All possible subset sums?   Does it need a better name?  The fact that your elements and sums are vector valued suggests that any special term you want to apply can and should be defined in the introduction of any write-up.

Comment: right, so maybe I should remove the real-valued part, by defining some additive group. but overall I'm trying to find the right keyword to search for some convex hull based on this type of set construction, specifically [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830257/find-extreme-points-with-complex-powerset-and-convex-combination-transformation)

Comment: I think you are asking (in the other Question) about the relationship between extreme points of the convex hull of a finite set $\mathscr S$ and the extreme points of finite subsets of $\mathscr S$. Any convex combinations of some points in $\mathbb R^n$ (resp. $\mathbb C^n$) [can be achieved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)) by using $n+1$ points (resp. $2n+1$ points).  Convex combinations (because they depend on a notion of betweenness) are inherently connected to real scalars, but the complex plane is a real vector space of dimension two.